# Why Maple fails to judge $x < \tan(x)$ assuming $0<x<\pi/2$?

Tags: maple

I am using maple to verify an expression, $x < \tan(x)$ for $0 < x < \pi/2$, but it returns **FAIL**, i.e.

```
is ( x < tan(x) ) assuming 0 < x < Pi/2
```

which returns *FAIL*.

I am very curious to know why this in-equality cannot be evealuated by Maple? I can evaluate is by computing the following

```
f := x -> tan(x) - x
g := x -> diff(f(x), x)
is (g(x) > 0) assuming 0 < x < Pi/2
```

which returns *true*.

Note1: Maple uses 3-valued logic for boolean operations, true, false and FAIL, where FAIL is returned whenever Maple is unable to evaluate a proposition with certainty.

Note2: Maple is a proprietary computer algebraic system that I have access through my university's lab.

Comment: Ali jan aya ino tu Mapleprime.com matrah kardi? Age jawabi naymad unja ham ye try bokon. :-)

Comment: Salam, hamin kar ro kardam. albate javab haye jalebi gereftam, vali yeki do rooz vaght verify kardaneshon ro nadaram. be mahze inke javab khoobi begiram, ersal mikonam inja.

Comment: Mamnun. man montazeram. sign bede waghti jawab gerefti. :-)